# How can I implement this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models, User, Group and Child. A user can create a group, can also add a child with the following associations.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
  belongs_to :group, optional: true
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group, optional: true
end
```

I need guidance on how to add a child to a group. How can I implement this in a controller?

Answer (score 0):

[`has_many`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) adds a salad of methods for working with the association.

`create!` lets you create a Child object associated with the Group.

```
group.children.create!(
  ...Child parameters...
)
```

`<<` will let you add an existing Child object to the Group.

```
child = Child.new(...Child parameters...)
group.children << child
```